# Reading a textfile

Tags: c++

My textfile looks like this:

```
1 41 -1 -1.492 -2.9555
1 42 -1 -1.49515 -2.9745
1 43 -1 -1.49799 -2.99361
1 44 -1 -1.50051 -3.01283
1 45 -1 -1.5027 -3.03213
1 46 -1 -1.50416 -3.05301
1 47 -1 -1.50556 -3.07248
```

(The numbers are separated by a space, not a tab.)

I'd like to write a program in C++ that reads these values and puts them into a vector, but how can I do this?

I tried this:

```cpp
while(!file.eof()){
    scanf("%d %d %d %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &eta, &phi);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me why and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Each line in avector or each number in a vector?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` in C++, you have `std::cin`.

Comment: You say your attempt does not work, but what went wrong with it?  A quick glance suggests it ought to read the values correctly, so is it storing them in your vector that failed?

Comment: `scanf()` is for reading `stdin`, `fscanf()` is for reading from files (which I presume is the case given `!file.eof()`). Check the result of `scanf()` to determine if successful and don't use `while(!file.eof())`. c++ has (typesafe) streams.

Comment: Each number in different vector, that's mean that i have five vector, one vector for x, on for y, one for z, one for eta, one for phi.
i think the lecture is wrong, because i have put a cout in this while and when i run the program this line had never printed...

I post the next line of the code:
while(!file.eof()){
scanf("%*d %d %d %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &eta, &phi);
cout<<"x"<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<z<<" "<<eta<<" "<<phi<<endl;
X.push_back(x);
Y.push_back(y);
Z.push_back(z);
Eta.push_back(eta);
Phi.push_back(phi);}
Can are you more explicit? I can't programm, so i don't understand what you have said.

Comment: `while .eof()` is wrong. Who taught you to do this?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean for you?

Comment: Why while(!file.eof) in wrong? in other program i use it.I think it reads the lines of my file.
it doesn't work mean that the program is correct, because when I compile I haven't errors, but when i execute it, it enter in a while but it doesen't print the cout, that I have put for control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in **C++** so do not use `scanf`, prefer `std::ifstream` instead.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream file("input.txt");
int x, y, z;
float eta, phi;
// Read you file until the end
while( file >> x >> y >> z >> eta >> phi )
{  
     // Print the values
     cout << "x : " << x << " y :" << y << " z : " << z << " eta : " << eta << " phi : " << phi << endl;
}
```

As Armen Tsirunyan shown, you can also use a `struct` to store the data with a `vector`. It depends what you want to do with your data.

The advantage of a structure is that you have an entity representing a lign with all the data. And you can overload an `operator>>` to read the file with cleaner code.

The code will look like this :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct s_Data
{
    int x, y, z;
    float eta, phi;
};

istream& operator >> (istream& iIn, s_Data& iData)
{
    return iIn >> iData.x >> iData.y >> iData.z >> iData.eta >> iData.phi;
}

ifstream file("input.txt");
// Read you file until the end
s_Data data;
vector<s_Data> datas;
while( file >> data )
{
     // Print the values
     cout << "x : " << data.x << " y :" << data.y << " z : " << data.z << " eta : " << data.eta << " phi : " << data.phi << endl;

     // Store the values
     datas.push_back( data );
}
```

Here `s_Data` represent your lign with the 5 values you want. The `vector<s_Data>` represents all the values read in the file. You can read it by doing :

```
unsigned int size = datas.size();
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    cout << datas[i].x;  // read all the x values for example
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have resolved.
If I don't want to use a struct and I declare 5 different vector, What is the difference?

Comment: It is a better practice to use a struct in that case. I suppose that your `x`, `y`, `z`, `eta`, `phi` of each line belong to a same entity or calculus right ? In that case it would be better to store them in the same entity (`struct`). Can you please mark the answer as accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put them in a char array and then convert them to float using `atof` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/). I usually use `fstream` library and I read them as a char array and then convert them to float/int etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to have as many vectors as you have lines in your file. If you're not interested in that, you can just use a simple `std::vector<double>` and use push back your values using the `std::copy`

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::istream &is = file; // thanks to polymorphism
std::string str;
std::vector<std::vector<double> > vects;
while ( str = getline(is) )
{
    std::vector<double> tmpVect;
    std::copy (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(is), 
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               std::back_inserter(tmpVect));
    vects.push_back(tmpVect); 
}
```

This `std::copy` will go through the entire line, calling `push_back` on the temporary vector with the value it just grabbed from the line.

**EDIT :**
After reading your comment, I believe this is actually not what you ask but it can be helpful in other situations. Please edit your original post to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>

struct MyData
{
    int x, y, z;
    double phi, eta;
};

vector<MyData> v;
ifstream fin("input.txt");
MyData d;
while(fin >> d.x >> d.y >> d.z >> d.phi >> d.eta)
{  
     v.push_back(d);
}
```

Or, you can overload operator >> and do this:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyData& d)
{
    return in >> d.x >> d.y >> d.z >> d.phi >> d.eta;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin ("input.txt");
    vector<MyData> v;
    v.assign(istream_iterator<MyData>(fin), istream_iterator<MyData>());
}
```

Comment: The same I've said to wrousseau goes for you. Please don't post code only answer, especially if do not have a single comment.

Comment: Armen Tsirunyan in this way, Where does I read all the lines of my file?

Comment: it's complicate...i can't undertand it...sorry :-(

Answer (score -1):

scanf returns -1 when nothing is read. You can do.

```
while(scanf()>=0)
{

}
```